# Link both openblas and mkl library while compiling c++

Tags: c++, linker, intel-mkl, openblas

I want to write a program to compare openblas and mkl library for matrix multiplication but I seem to have a problem while linking both these libraries as they share same function hence gives "confliction error" with g++.

They seem to run individually in different cpp files using

```
g++ matrixmult_openblas.cpp -I /usr/local/opt/OpenBLAS/include/ -L/usr/local/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas
```

and

```
g++ matrixmult_mkl.cpp -L${MKLROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${MKLROOT}/lib -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs_mpich_ilp64 -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

How do I compile them in a single cpp file?
I have used namespaces like these

```
namespace openblas
{
    #include <cblas.h>
}
namespace mkl
{
    #include <mkl.h>
}
```

When I compile them using both linkers like,

```
g++ matrixmult.cpp -I /usr/local/opt/OpenBLAS/include/ -L/usr/local/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas -L${MKLROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${MKLROOT}/lib -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lmkl_blacs_mpich_ilp64 -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

I'm getting errors like

> In file included from /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/mac/mkl/include/mkl.h:31:
>   /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/mac/mkl/include/mkl_cblas.h:255:6: error: conflicting types for 'cblas_sgemv'
>   void cblas_sgemv(const  CBLAS_LAYOUT Layout,
>        ^
>   /usr/local/opt/OpenBLAS/include/cblas.h:125:6: note: previous declaration is here

Please help me do this.
I want an output file in which I can pass argument 'openblas' or 'mkl' to main function to use whichever library.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm getting errors like
>
> > ```
> > In file included from /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/mac/mkl/include/mkl.h:31:
> > ```
> >
> > /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/mac/mkl/include/mkl_cblas.h:255:6:
> >     error: conflicting types for 'cblas_sgemv' void cblas_sgemv(const
> >     CBLAS_LAYOUT Layout, ^ /usr/local/opt/OpenBLAS/include/cblas.h:125:6:
> >     note: previous declaration is here

You are lucky.  Under other circumstances you might instead have had your program compile successfully without error, and then behave unexpectedly at run time.

> How do I compile them in a single cpp file?

You don't.  OpenBLAS and MKL provide routines having the same names and with C linkage.  Even if they had compatible types, the compiled program would use only one of each pair.  You cannot work around this by manipulating declarations or header files, as those need to match the actual compiled functions in order to be of any use.

> I want to write a program to compare openblas and mkl library for matrix multiplication

You'll have to settle for writing *two* programs, one for each library.  Make them as similar as possible, and compare their behavior on the same (or equivalent) inputs.

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind some overhead and just want to compare two libraries you can try GSL. In fact, all its BLAS functions are just wrappers which allow you to have the same code but link different linear algebra subroutines.